# How to fix black bars in Unity2D android game

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, camera, game-development

I am making an android game, but when I build the apk and run it on my mobile then it shows me the black bars on the side. The game is in landscape mode, and the camera is in a perspective mode in Unity. How do I fix it?

Comment: You need to share my details like Unity Version, Android Device Name, Android OS Version, …

Comment: I am using Unity 5.6 and the android 11

Answer (score 0):

Player Settings -> Android -> Resolution and Presentation

Set `Aspect Ratio Mode` to `Custom`

Set `Up To` value to `2.2` (or even larger).

---

For legacy versions,

Android >= 8.0, add `android:maxAspectRatio` to unity activity

```
<activity
    android:maxAspectRatio="2.2"
    android:resizeableActivity="true" />
```

Android < 8.0, add `android.max_aspect` to application tag

```
<application>
    <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.2" />
```

Comment: I dont have suvh option in unity 5.6

Comment: It's still the same, I tried pasting this command in the activity tag and then inside the intent-filter tag in the activity tag, I also tried replacing another meta tag with the same name but different values, but the result is still the same, plz help!

Comment: @Aditya updated my answer, since you are using Android 11, you may use `maxAspectRatio` attribute. And make sure you have chosen `Fullscreen Window` in player settings.

Comment: There is no option for the fullscreen window in android player settings, and the solution still don't work for me, here is activity tag-
 <activity
            android:label="@ref/0x7f030000"
            android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
            android:launchMode="2"
            android:screenOrientation="8"
            android:configChanges="0x40003fff"
            android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity"
            android:value="true">

Comment: Have you added maxAspectRatio? Is target sdk version >= 26?

Comment: Yes, I have added the maxAspectRatio and my target SDK version is 32. One more thing, if I force enable fullscreen mode from my mobile settings then the game works in fullscreen without any issue